# Post Pagination does not working on WP-Query

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

I've created a custom function name default_query(); 
Everything same as default query. I'm accepting arguments on this function using on Global Query.
I'm facing problem on Pagination. It's not about single post pagination. It's pagination like 1,2,3...end

```
$pwpt_query = (isset($atts) && ($atts['default_query'] === false)) ? new WP_Query($atts) : $wp_query;
$atts = (isset($atts)) ? $atts : array();

$exc_lnth = option_vs_default('excerpt_length_more', 55);
$excerpt_length = (isset($atts['excerpt_length']) && $atts['excerpt_length'] != '') ? $atts['excerpt_length'] : $exc_lnth;

$show_excerpt = ($excerpt_length == '0' || !$pwpt_show->excerpt) ? false : true;

$title_size = pwpt_get_blog_loop_title_size($atts, 2);

$text_align = pwpt_get_blog_loop_text_align($atts);

if($pwpt_query->have_posts()) { 
  while($pwpt_query->have_posts()){

    // Content Block

    $pwpt_query->the_post();

  }}

the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Previous', 'jeweltheme' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'jeweltheme' ),
) );
```

Can anyone help me about this ?

Comment: please post the full code of your function

Comment: What exactly are the results you're seeing?

Comment: @Michael I cann't see anything changes.

Comment: @belinus> Updated full Code Block.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what problem you're having though. Is pagination simply not showing up? Is it showing up weird? How many posts are in your site?

Comment: Pagination not showing. If it messed up then I could handle this. But no pagination is showing.

Comment: `the_posts_pagination()` only works with the default `$wp_query`, not custom queries.